# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class AppTwo extends Component{
    render(){
        return console.log('test')
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<AppTwo />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'this' in line 4
In this condition when i create-new-app in react JS

Comment: forgot to import `Component ` or use `Reac. Component `

Comment: Also `render(){
        return console.log('test')
    }` this is invalid implementation. It has to return something, atleast `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class AppTwo extends Component{
    render(){
       return(
              <div>test</div>
             );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<AppTwo />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class AppTwo extends React.Component{
    render(){
      console.log('test')
       return(
              <div>test</div>
             );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<AppTwo />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

try this code, and learn  more about react